# How to use Linux zip to sync files

Tags: linux, sync, zip

I want to "sync" my files to the zip, creating any new ones, updating any new ones, and the deleting ones from the zip that no longer exist.

When I used `-du`, I see

```
zip error: Invalid command arguments (specify just one action)
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this is to delete the entire file and zip the dir again.

The '-d' parameter expects relative file path to delete given files from zip. The '-u' option adds (or updates) new files to the zip. They cannot be used together.

I'm not sure if you can do the update/delete easily using the zip command. However I wrote you a simple script below which can do what you want. Feel free to edit the script - for now it requires the archive and the directory which you want to zip/update to be in the same place (for example /home/you/archive.zip and /home/you/directory_to_zip. Additionally it does not add empty directories to the zip.

```
#!/bin/bash

archive="archive_name.zip"
directory="dir_to_zip"

#Get list of files in archive
filesinarchive=`unzip -l $archive | sed 's/[ ][ ]*/ /g' | grep 2014 | cut -d" " -f 5 | sort`

#Uncomment when debugging
#echo -e "Files in archive:\n$filesinarchive"

#Get list of files in directory..
filesindirectory=`find $directory/ -type f | sort`

#Uncomment when debugging
#echo -e "\n\nFiles in Directory:\n$filesindirectory"

#Save the lists to tmp files..
echo "$filesinarchive" > /tmp/fia
echo "$filesindirectory" > /tmp/fid


#Compare file lists and return the files present in archive and NOT present in directory
remove=$(comm -1 -3 /tmp/fid /tmp/fia)

#Uncomment when debugging
#echo -e "\n\n\n Files to be deleted:\n$remove \n\n"


#Now delete these files from zip
for file in $remove
do
        zip -d $archive $file
done


#We have deleted files which were not present in the directory, now we need to update our zip:
zip -R -u $archive $filesindirectory

#delete temp files
rm -f /tmp/fia /tmp/fid
```

Save the contents above to the file called zipsync.sh, give it execute permissions (chmod +x zipsync) and run when being in directory with the archive and the directory to zip.

You can modify the script so that it can take non-relative paths and/or zip empty directories.

Hope this helps a little.

Comment: Thanks you. The reason I didn't want to start over (if possible) is because it is faster to only change the files that have changed.

Comment: No problem. Please mark the question as answered or vote up if it was helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`fuse-zip`](https://code.google.com/p/fuse-zip/).  From the project description:

> `fuse-zip` is a FUSE file system to navigate, extract, create and modify ZIP archives based in libzip implemented in C++.
>
> With fuse-zip you really can work with ZIP archives as real directories. Unlike KIO or Gnome VFS, it can be used in any application without modifications.

This makes it possible to "mount" a zip archive at some directory.  Look at [the documentation](https://code.google.com/p/fuse-zip/wiki/About) for examples.